# What are possible reasons that I got messages from kafka topic sometimes only?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-python

I'm using confluent_kafka package in python to do event streaming locally. There are multiple stages in my program. The first stage sends output as a message to a topic designated to the next stage. Each subsequent stage does the same (retrieve message from the designated topic and send event to another topic).

The problem is, the second stages onward, I can only get messages lower than 5% of the time. For example, in the topic first stage sends to, I've checked using terminal that there are over 100 messages in that topic, but I only got 2 messages in the next stage. It's not entirely not working cuz I do get some of them, but I can't figure out where went wrong.

Any idea? Appreciate any help!

Here is the main part of my producer

```
producer = Producer({'bootstrap.servers': "localhost:9092"})
producer.produce("first_topic", key=event_key, value=json.dumps(event, indent=4, default= str))
producer.flush()
```

Here is the main part of my consumer

```
            conf = {'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092',
                    'group.id': 'a_group',
                    'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest'}
            consumer = Consumer(conf)
            consumer.subscribe(topic)
            
            msg = consumer.poll(timeout=1.0)
            if msg is None:
                print("No message available.") 
                pass
            
            if msg.error():
                if msg.error().code() == KafkaError._PARTITION_EOF:
                    # End of partition event
                    sys.stderr.write('%% %s [%d] reached end at offset %d\n' %
                                    (msg.topic(), msg.partition(), msg.offset()))
                    print("Error partition_eof")
                elif msg.error():
                    raise KafkaException(msg.error())
            else:
                key = msg.key().decode("utf-8")
                data = msg.value().decode("utf-8")
                return data
```

Answer (score 0):

You've set a group.id and you're only polling one event from this code. Consumers typically run endlessly using a while loop, and wait for any events to be processed.

Otherwise, you need some type of cron process to keep running your consumer app, and you'll need to handle offset commits manually.

Kafka isn't typically used in request-reply patterns, so your `return data` statement isn't guaranteed to happen within any time frame